# Wordpress : wpdb prepare with conditional

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use `sql->prepare` with many strings concatenation.

In my code below, I try to call a function which will return me an array of `get_post` from `$wpdb->prepare`.

```
function test($array){
    $sqlprep = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  p.ID 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts  p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)  
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships r1 ON (p.ID = r1.object_id) 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships r2 ON (p.ID = r2.object_id) 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id AND t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE 1=1";

    if(isset($array['post_type']) && !empty($array['post_type']){
        $sqlprep .= " AND p.post_type = '".$array['post_type']."'";
    }
    if(isset($array['post_type']) && !empty($array['post_type']){
        $sqlprep .= " AND p.post_type = '".$array['post_status']."'";
    }

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sqlprep);
    $ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    return array_map('get_post', $ids)
}
```

and the value is an array which is :

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'published',
);
```

When I try to `print_r($sql)` to get the query, it always just stop till `WHERE 1=1`.

Can string concatenation be used for `wpdb prepare`?

Comment: You can use concatenation with prepare. Whether you should is a different question! In your code you miss a closing parentheses in each of your if statements; and also a semicolon in your return statement. I'm surprised you don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to the use of the properties in the $wpdb object and the use of the prepare method, furthermore there is an issue with the column name for the post_status:

```
function test($array){
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  p.ID 
        FROM {$wpdb->posts}  p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} m ON m.post_id = p.ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)  
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} r1 ON (p.ID = r1.object_id) 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} r2 ON (p.ID = r2.object_id) 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id AND t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE 1=1";

    if(isset($array['post_type']) && !empty($array['post_type']){
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND p.post_type = %s", $array['post_type']);
    }
    if(isset($array['post_type']) && !empty($array['post_type']){
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare(" AND p.post_status = %s", $array['post_status']);
    }

    $ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    return array_map('get_post', $ids)
}
```